# Any way to export images from ArcGIS FeatureServer?

Tags: arcgis-online, export

I'm trying to export images from an ArcGIS server.

Exporting `MapServer` layer images is just okay, but `FeatureServer` doesn't support exporting to images. Although it can `query` for features and the layerInfo contains `drawingInfo`.

Also the server can display the features in the map.

Current idea is to use selenium, but moving map will be tough one.

Anyone knows about a tool that would do the job?

Comment: Have you tried creating a selection on the feature service and using the CopyFeatures tool?

Comment: @Bjorn no, I haven't. The ArcGIS is not managed by me, also I don't have ArcGIS for desktop. The goal is to export images via script.